# Change Annotations before sending component on Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developping an app on Angular 2 and in this app I need to change dynamically some attributes inside @Component decorator. Here is my code :

```
function componentFactory (directives: any[], template: string) {
    let annotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', ComponentBase)
    annotations[0].directives = directives
    annotations[0].template = template

    let metadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotations)
    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], ComponentBase)

    return ComponentBase
}
```

The problem is that when I use it (with a ComponentResolver) I get this error : "Component 'ComponentBase' must have either 'template' or 'templateUrl' set.".

Do you have any suggestions ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically change some attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @pablo. I need to add directives in my component without knowing which ones I want to use. I've managed to make it work but this is not a good practice (declaring the same classe multiple times) :

    function componentFactory (directives: any[], template: string) {
        @Component({
            directives: directives,
            template: template,
        })

        class ComponentBase {}

        return ComponentBase
    }

Comment: Maybe you could use the Component Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found how to create dynamic components

```
function createDynamicComponent<T extends IBase> (componentAttributes: any, SuperClass: IConstructor<T>) {
    class DynamicComponent extends (<IConstructor<IBase>> SuperClass) {}

    return Component(componentAttributes)(DynamicComponent)
}

interface IConstructor<T> {
    new (...args): T
}

interface IBase {}
```

I forgot that we can use decorators as functions ;)